# Illegal character error in jquery

Tags: jquery, select, alert

I'm selecting the text value of the selected value of a drop down list. But i get this error. `illegal character`  rname is just a string value. Can anyone help me solve this?

```
alert($("#presetname-"+rname+" option:selected").text());
```

Help much appreciated.

Update:

```
 $('body').find('#toolbar-'+rname).val(selected_preset);
 $('body').find('#presetname-'+rname).val(selected_preset);
 var e="#presetname-"+rname;
  alert($(e+" option:selected").text());​
```

there are no errors above the final line everything works fine above, so rname value is correct.

Comment: What does `rname` resolve to ?

Comment: What is rname ?? unique identifier for the selectbox ?

Comment: im grabbing the id value of `<select>` its like `id=presetname-text`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#presentname option:selected").text();
```

should be enough to select the text value selected in the drop-down list.

Make sure you have jQuery in your page, meaning you have a `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>` in your `head`.

I've done a simple example, as follows:

```
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id = presentname>
        <option name="1">aa</option>
        <option name="2">bb</option>
    </select>
</body>
```

Now, if I do a `alert($("#presentname option:selected").text());`, an alert containing **aa** pops up on the screen.

Comment: just doesn't work, because identifier is incorrect, and it alerts a blank alert box.

Comment: Im sorry but this isn't what i want. I need that rname value as a part of id value. it jst has to be there. i know yours will work. but thats not a solution for my questoin.

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting the rname correctly i think...try alerting the rname first

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
    var rname = 1; //making an unique identifier
    alert($("#presetname-"+rname+" option:selected").text());
    });
    });

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <select id="presetname-1">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>  
      </select>
      <button>Get</button>  
    </body>
    </html>
```